# Safe Distance away Radioactive Lens?

Tags: lens, old-lenses

Is it correct that when you move at least 3 feet away from a radioactive that level drop dramatically to safe levels and even further a way - as little as 10-12 feet-levels drop to background levels indoors?

Comment: Did you check the emissions from the "radioactive" lens? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger_counter

Comment: Please define "Safe levels". Exposure is always a combination of intensity and duration of exposure.

Comment: How did your lens become radioactive?  It matters whether the radioactivity is alpha, beta, or gamma rays.  It also matters how radioactive it is.

Comment: @RossMillikan [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoriated_glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoriated_glass)

Comment: The primary radiation from thorium is alpha particles.  They are stopped by about 1/4 inch (6 mm) of air.  There will be some gamma radiation as well, but not too much.  They fall off as the square of the distance, but not much more than that.

Answer (score 4):

Though the lens might contain substantial amounts of thorium (Th, with <sup>232</sup>Th the most common isotope), most of the radiation is blocked by the glass itself (eventually turning it brown). Still, the surface emits some alpha particles, as @RossMillikan (any relative of the physicist?) stated. Keeping it in a container more than a few millimeters thick (e.g., a plastic box), will block all the <sup>232</sup>Th alpha particles.

There are, however, [**decay products** from Th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorium-232), such as radium (Ra) and radon (Rn), and these emit more radiation and decay into other radioactive species. The half-life of <sup>232</sup>Th is 14,000,000,000 years, about the age of the universe, which means that it is not *intensely* radioactive, and the majority is sealed in glass. You might not want to keep it in a living space because of Rn outgassing. Handle it *only* while wearing disposable rubber or vinyl gloves, because of those decay products.

This is **not** meant to be considered medical or radiological safety advice. See other sites, such as [Movie Cultists](https://moviecultists.com/is-thoriated-glass-dangerous) and [Lens Legend](https://lenslegend.com/radioactive-lenses/), too. And do **not** use a thoriated eyepiece (ocular) lens.

Comment: FWIW, due to decay product formation, these lenses become *more* radioactive over time -- because the decay products have shorter half lives than the natural thorium.  There's also beta emission from the decay products, though alpha and gamma are the bulk of the emissions.  Even one of these lenses 50-60 years old won't emit enough noticeably to fog film through a cloth shutter (I have one of these, a Super Takumar 50/1.4, that lived on my Spotmatic for close to thirty years), suggesting the beta and gamma emission, at least, remain quite low.

Comment: "You might not want to keep it in a living space because of Rn outgassing. Handle it only while wearing disposable rubber or vinyl gloves, because of those decay products" usually neither suggestion is needed given the amount of decay products and the rate of release from the glass. It's much safer that one would understand by reading this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, don't eat it, don't inhale it and don't bring radioactive lenses directly next to your eyeball - meaning, less than a few (~6) millimetres away.

Under no circumstances should radioactive lenses be destroyed by crushing, or other physical force - that action would release huge amounts of tiny particles that could be inhaled and could come with direct contact with eyes, skin and hair, and stay there for a prolonged time. That would be the worst-case scenario, better keep it in the lens drawer, or cabinet, with both lens caps on.

Answer (score 2):

I made specific simulations of a real thoriated lens placed near the eye using a software for this purpose which involves a detailed (1 mm resolution) model of the human body. So I know what I'm talking about.

I don't remember the numbers but the resulting exposure to the eye is negligible, assuming you use the lens as it's supposed to be used: mounted on a camera and placed near the eye only while shooting, so basically don't stick the lens to your everyday glasses to have it near the eye the whole time (but why would you anyway?).

So, for use as a camera lens, zero issues.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what the radiation is that's emitted, how intense that radiation is (energy levels), and where within the lens body the emissions are taking place.

If it's alpha emissions from inner lens elements (rather than the front or rear elements) there's nothing really to worry about as those will get blocked by the other materials in the lens, even by your skin and clothing unless it's REALLY high amounts.

Beta too will generally get blocked well by glass and metals.

Gamma isn't blocked by anything but will get attenuated by anything it passes through.

For commercial products (rather than highly specialised industrial or scientific ones) anything sold should conform to consumer safety rules and be safe to handle without special tooling or protective equipment unless such is explicitly mentioned in the product manual.

For industrial and scientific equipment the rules are a bit more lenient, but also would include instructions for protection (if needed) in the manual (mostly what's more lenient are the amounts of radiation various professional groups are allowed to be exposed to per year IF they are workers required to wear radiation badges).

So the only potentially dangerous equipment would be that that's been accidentally exposed. THAT stuff you should not handle without safety precautions, unless it's been cleaned and said to be safe for outsiders to handle by an expert. Such equipment obviously is very rare outside labs handling radioactive material regularly, so you're unlikely to ever come into contact with it unless you work in such an environment and if you did you'd have known all this already. Leaves something you picked up in the Chernobyl or Fukushima exclusion zones, which might be somewhat radioactive due to contamination from fallout. Don't handle such things,  call your nearest physics department or if none are nearby hospital with cancer treatment facilities and ask them to come dispose of it safely.

That's my take as a physicist who graduated in nuclear waste classification. Don't take it as medical advise (see a doctor specialising in nuclear medicine for that), but that's the long and short from an engineering perspective.

Comment: "anything sold should conform to consumer safety rules" while true _today_, the [lenses that we're talking about here are vintage lenses (pre-1970)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoriated_glass) when consumer safety rules etc were not nearly as robust as they are now.